# PHP Collection - Code Duplication upon refresh or page change

Tags: php, function, duplication

I have created some custom code (lines 287-309 in the code below)It is a duplicate function of  313-345 but with a few changes.

Although the function works perfectly well for some reason the page upon change or refresh duplicate the collection at the bottom of the page.

If I move lines 287-309 to line 347 onwards this does not happen. I'm assuming I a creating some sort of loop here or am I not closing the PHP correctly?

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

The Code:

```
<?php
include "../include/db.php";
include "../include/authenticate.php";
include "../include/general.php";
include "../include/resource_functions.php";
include "../include/collections_functions.php";

hook("homeheader");

include "../include/header.php";

if (!hook("replacehome")) { 

if (!hook("replaceslideshow")) { 

# Count the files in the configured $homeanim_folder.
$dir = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../" . $homeanim_folder; 
$filecount = 0; 
$checksum=0; # Work out a checksum which is the total of all the image files in bytes - used in image URLs to force a refresh if any of the images change.
$d = scandir($dir); 
sort($d, SORT_NUMERIC);
$reslinks=array();
foreach ($d as $f) { 
 if(preg_match("/[0-9]+\.(jpg)/",$f))
{ 
$filecount++; 
$checksum+=filesize($dir . "/" . $f);
$linkfile=substr($f,0,(strlen($f)-4)) . ".txt";
$reslinks[$filecount]="";
if(file_exists("../" . $homeanim_folder . "/" . $linkfile))
    {
    $linkref=file_get_contents("../" . $homeanim_folder . "/" . $linkfile);
    $linkaccess = get_resource_access($linkref);
    if (($linkaccess!=="") && (($linkaccess==0) || ($linkaccess==1))){$reslinks[$filecount]=$baseurl . "/pages/view.php?ref=" . $linkref;}
    }   
}
} 

$homeimages=$filecount;
if ($filecount>1) { # Only add Javascript if more than one image.
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

var num_photos=<?php echo $homeimages?>;  // <---- number of photos (/images/slideshow?.jpg)
var photo_delay=5; // <---- photo delay in seconds
var link = new Array();

<?php 
$l=1;
foreach ($reslinks as $reslink)
{
echo "link[" . $l . "]=\"" .  $reslink . "\";";
$l++;
}
?>

var cur_photo=2;
var last_photo=1;
var next_photo=2;

flip=1;

var image1=0;
var image2=0;



function nextPhoto()
{
if (!document.getElementById('image1')) {return false;} /* Photo slideshow no longer available (AJAX page move) */

  if (cur_photo==num_photos) {next_photo=1;} else {next_photo=cur_photo+1;}


  image1 = document.getElementById("image1");
  image2 = document.getElementById("photoholder");
  sslink = document.getElementById("slideshowlink");
  linktarget=link[cur_photo];
  if (flip==0)
    {
    // image1.style.visibility='hidden';
    //Effect.Fade(image1);
    jQuery('#image1').fadeOut(1000)
    window.setTimeout("image1.src='<?php echo $baseurl . "/" . $homeanim_folder?>/" + next_photo + ".jpg?checksum=<?php echo $checksum ?>';if(linktarget!=''){jQuery('#slideshowlink').attr('href',linktarget);}else{jQuery('#slideshowlink').removeAttr('href');}",1000);
    flip=1;
    }
  else
    {
    // image1.style.visibility='visible';
    //Effect.Appear(image1);
    jQuery('#image1').fadeIn(1000)
    window.setTimeout("image2.style.background='url(<?php echo $baseurl . "/" .  $homeanim_folder?>/" + next_photo + ".jpg?checksum=<?php echo $checksum ?>)';if(linktarget!=''){jQuery('#slideshowlink').attr('href',linktarget);}else{jQuery('#slideshowlink').removeAttr('href');}",1000);
    flip=0;
    }       

  last_photo=cur_photo;
  cur_photo=next_photo;
  timers.push(window.setTimeout("nextPhoto()", 1000 * photo_delay));
}

jQuery(document).ready( function ()
{ 
/* Clear all old timers */
ClearTimers();
timers.push(window.setTimeout("nextPhoto()", 1000 * photo_delay));
}
);

</script>
<?php } ?>



<div class="HomePicturePanel"

<?php if (isset($home_slideshow_width)) {
echo "style=\"";
$slide_width = $home_slideshow_width + 0;
echo"width:" .  (string)$slide_width ."px; ";
echo "\" ";
}
?>>

<a id="slideshowlink"
<?php

$linkurl="#";
if(file_exists("../" . $homeanim_folder . "/1.txt"))
    {
    $linkres=file_get_contents("../" . $homeanim_folder . "/1.txt");
    $linkaccess = get_resource_access($linkres);
    if (($linkaccess!=="") && (($linkaccess==0) || ($linkaccess==1))) {$linkurl=$baseurl . "/pages/view.php?ref=" . $linkres;}
    echo "href=\"" . $linkurl ."\" ";
    }   

?>
\>

<div class="HomePicturePanelIN" id='photoholder' style="
<?php
if (isset($home_slideshow_height)){     
    echo"height:" .  (string)$home_slideshow_height ."px; ";
    } 
?>

background-image:url('<?php echo $baseurl . "/" . $homeanim_folder?>/1.jpg?checksum=<?php echo $checksum ?>');">



<img src='<?php echo $baseurl . "/" .  $homeanim_folder?>/2.jpg?checksum=<?php echo $checksum ?>' alt='' id='image1' style="display:none;<?php
if (isset($home_slideshow_width)){
    echo"width:" .  $home_slideshow_width ."px; ";
    }
if (isset($home_slideshow_height)){
    echo"height:" .  $home_slideshow_height ."px; ";
    } 
?>">
</div>
</a>

<div class="PanelShadow"></div>
</div>




<?php } # End of hook replaceslideshow
?>



<?php if (checkperm("s")) {
hook("homebeforepanels");
?>

<?php if ($home_themeheaders && $enable_themes) { ?>
<div class="HomePanel"><div class="HomePanelIN">
<h2><a onClick="return CentralSpaceLoad(this,true);" href="<?php echo $baseurl_short?>pages/themes.php"><?php echo $lang["themes"]?></a></h2>
<?php echo text("themes")?>
<br />  <br />
<select style="width:140px;" onChange="CentralSpaceLoad(this.value,true);">
<option value=""><?php echo $lang["select"] ?></option>
<?php
$headers=get_theme_headers();
for ($n=0;$n<count($headers);$n++)
    {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $baseurl_short?>pages/themes.php?header=<?php echo urlencode($headers[$n])?>"><?php echo i18n_get_translated(str_replace("*","",$headers[$n]))?></option>
    <?php
    }
?>
</select>
<br />&gt;&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo $baseurl_short?>pages/themes.php" onClick="return CentralSpaceLoad(this,true);"><?php echo $lang["viewall"] ?></a>
</div>



<div class="PanelShadow"></div>
</div>



<?php } ?>



<?php if ($home_themes && $enable_themes) { ?>
<div class="HomePanel"><div class="HomePanelINtopA">
<div class="HomePanelINtopHeader"><a href="<?php echo $baseurl_short?>pages/themes.php" onClick="return CentralSpaceLoad(this,true);" style="color:#ffffff;"><?php echo $lang["themes"]?></a></div>
<div class="HomePanelINtopText"><?php echo text("themes")?></div>
</div>
<div class="PanelShadow"></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($home_mycollections && !checkperm("b") && $userrequestmode!=2 && $userrequestmode!=3) { ?>
<div class="HomePanel"><div class="HomePanelINtopB">
<div class="HomePanelINtopHeader"><a href="<?php echo $baseurl_short?>pages/collection_manage.php" onClick="return CentralSpaceLoad(this,true);" style="color:#ffffff;">                        <?php echo $lang["mycollections"]?></a></div>
<div class="HomePanelINtopText"><?php echo text("mycollections")?></div>
</div>
<div class="PanelShadow">
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($home_advancedsearch) { ?>
<div class="HomePanel"><div class="HomePanelINtopC">
<div class="HomePanelINtopHeader"><a href="<?php echo $baseurl_short?>pages/search_advanced.php" onClick="return CentralSpaceLoad(this,true);" style="color:#ffffff;">          <?php echo $lang["advancedsearch"]?></a></div>
<div class="HomePanelINtopText"><?php echo text("advancedsearch")?></div>
</div>
<div class="PanelShadow"></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($home_mycontributions && (checkperm("d") || (checkperm("c") && checkperm("e0")))) { ?>
<div class="HomePanel"><div class="HomePanelINtopD">
<div class="HomePanelINtopHeader"><a href="<?php echo $baseurl_short?>pages/contribute.php" onClick="return CentralSpaceLoad(this,true);" style="color:#ffffff;"><?php echo $lang["mycontributions"]?></a></div>
<div class="HomePanelINtopText"><?php echo text("mycontributions")?></div>
</div>
<div class="PanelShadow"></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($home_helpadvice) { ?>
<div class="HomePanel"><div class="HomePanelINtopE">
<div class="HomePanelINtopHeader"><a href="<?php echo $baseurl_short?>pages/help.php" onClick="return CentralSpaceLoad(this,true);" style="color:#ffffff;"><?php echo $lang["helpandadvice"]?></a></div>
<div class="HomePanelINtopText"><?php echo text("help")?></div>
</div>
<div class="PanelShadow"></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($home_themes && $enable_themes) { ?>
<div class="HomePanel"><div class="HomePanelINtopIntro">
<div class="HomePanelINtopHeader"><a href="<?php echo $baseurl_short?>pages/themes.php" onClick="return CentralSpaceLoad(this,true);" style="color:#ffffff;"><?php echo text("welcometitle")?></a></div>
<div class="HomePanelINtopText"><?php echo text("welcometext")?></div>
</div>
<div class="PanelShadow"></div>
</div>
<?php } ?>



<?php 
/* ------------ Customisable home page panels ------------------- */
if (isset($custom_home_panels))
{
for ($n=0;$n<count($custom_home_panels);$n++)
    {
    if (!hook("panelperm")) { 
    ?>
    <div class="HomePanel"><div class="HomePanelIN" <?php if ($custom_home_panels[$n]["text"]=="") {?>style="min-height:0;"<?php } ?>>
    <h2><a href="<?php echo $custom_home_panels[$n]["link"] ?>" <?php if (isset($custom_home_panels[$n]["additional"])){ echo $custom_home_panels[$n]["additional"];} ?>>           <?php echo i18n_get_translated($custom_home_panels[$n]["title"]) ?></a></h2>
    <?php echo i18n_get_translated($custom_home_panels[$n]["text"]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="PanelShadow"></div>
    </div>
    <?php
    } // end hook 'panelperm'
    }
}
?>




<!--  THIS IS LINE 287 please refer to question --> 
<?php 
if(!hook("EditorsPick")):
/* ------------ Collections promoted to the home page ------------------- */
$home_collectionsx=get_home_page_promoted_collectionsx(16);
foreach ($home_collectionsx as $home_collectionx)
{
?>
<div class="EditorsPick">
<div class="HomePanel"><div class="HomePanelINtopEditors">
<div class="HomePanelINtopHeader">Editors Pick</div>
<div class="HomePanelINtopText">This is the editors pick of Asset Space...</div>
<div class="EditorsPicImage"><div style="padding-top:<?php echo floor((155-$home_collectionx["thumb_height"])/2) ?>px; margin-top: -24px; margin-bottom: -15px;">
<a href="<?php echo $baseurl_short?>pages/search.php?search=!collection<?php echo $home_collectionx["ref"] ?>" onClick="return CentralSpaceLoad(this,true);"><img class="ImageBorder" src="<?php echo get_resource_path($home_collectionx["home_page_image"],false,"thm",false) ?>" width="<?php echo $home_collectionx["thumb_width"] ?>" height="         <?php echo $home_collectionx["thumb_height"] ?>" /></div>
</div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
endif; # end hook homefeaturedcol
?> 
<!-- THIS IS LINE 309 please refer to question -->



<!-- THIS IS LINE 313 please refer to question -->  
<?php 
if(!hook("homefeaturedcol")):
/* ------------ Collections promoted to the home page ------------------- */
$home_collections=get_home_page_promoted_collections(16);
foreach ($home_collections as $home_collection)
{
?>
<div class="ResourceOfTheDay"></div>
<div class="HomePanel HomePanelPromoted"><div class="HomePanelIN HomePanelPromotedIN">
<div class="MyCollectionsHighlite"></div>
<div class="HomePanelPromotedImageWrap">


<div style="padding-top:<?php echo floor((155-$home_collection["thumb_height"])/2) ?>px; margin-top: -24px; margin-bottom: -15px;">
<a href="<?php echo $baseurl_short?>pages/search.php?search=!collection<?php echo $home_collection["ref"] ?>" onClick="return CentralSpaceLoad(this,true);"><img class="ImageBorder" src="<?php echo get_resource_path($home_collection["home_page_image"],false,"thm",false) ?>" width="<?php echo $home_collection["thumb_width"] ?>" height="<?php echo $home_collection["thumb_height"] ?>" /></div>
</div>

<p style="font-size:14px; font-weight:bold"><a href="<?php echo $baseurl_short?>pages/search.php?search=!collection<?php echo $home_collection["ref"] ?>" onClick="return CentralSpaceLoad(this,true);"><?php echo i18n_get_translated($home_collection["home_page_text"]) ?></a></p>

<p style="font-size:12px; font-weight:normal"><a href="<?php echo $baseurl_short?>pages/search.php?search=!collection<?php echo $home_collection["ref"] ?>" onClick="return CentralSpaceLoad(this,true);">Click to view this collection</a></p>

</div>

<div class="PanelShadow"></div>
</div>


<?php
}
endif; # end hook homefeaturedcol
?> 
<!-- THIS IS LINE 345 please refer to question -->

<!-- THIS IS LINE 347 please refer to question -->

<div class="clearerleft"></div>


<?php }

} // End of ReplaceHome hook

include "../include/footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: Can you add some obvious comment lines with line numbers, this will make it easier for us to see where you're talking about (not all line numbers, just the main ones e.g. 287,387,347)

Comment: Also, by '287-387' did you mean '287-307'

Comment: Ok added comments :-)

Comment: Both of those functions have invalid HTML - namely unmatched `a` element around the `img`

Comment: Can't see a loop or any reason for duplicates have you tried doing `echo '<pre>'.print_r($home_collectionsx,true).'</pre>';` before the `foreach` ?  Just to make sure the array contains what you think it does

Comment: Adding the closing </a> doesn't make any difference

Comment: Yup echo <pre> showing the correct output

Comment: And you say it works fine when you first visit the page, but breaks when you hit refresh?

Comment: Yep, works on the homepage, then if you go to another page it shows the collections at the bottom, then go back to homepage and you see the duplicated collections at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment above I would say this line is to blame:

```
if(!hook("homefeaturedcol")):
```

I'm assuming that this is running as well as your new code above it when it's not the homepage

You may also want to have a look at your HTML structure

Comment: Fixed :-) I had 1 to many </div> tags in the block of code - jeepers

Comment: @richyp147 Yea, the it all looked a bit confusing to be honest - you might want to improve the formatting of your code with indentation

Comment: I have one more for you if you wouldn't mind then I am fixed up, please could you look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879754/adjusting-a-function-to-show-a-specific-size-of-image

Comment: @richyp147 Sure - if my answers on this and the other question have helped and sorted out the issues, don't forget to mark the questions as resolved by accepting the answers.

Comment: Im new to this bud, how do I do that please - and yes you have been a massive help

Comment: Under the downvote arrow to the left of the answers should be a tick - just click that