# Adjusting a function to show a specific size of image

Tags: function, size

[image]

With the code below now working can anyone suggest how I pull out the image from the collection at a larger size, this is only working for thumbnails at the moment.

```
<?php 
if(!hook("EditorsPick")):
/* ------------ Collections promoted to the home page ------------------- */
$home_collectionsx=get_home_page_promoted_collectionsx(16);
foreach ($home_collectionsx as $home_collectionx)
    {
    ?>
<div class="EditorsPick">
   <div class="HomePanel"><div class="HomePanelINtopEditors">
    <div class="HomePanelINtopHeader">Editors Pick</div>
    <div class="HomePanelINtopText">This is the editors pick of Asset Space...</div>
   <div class="EditorsPicImage"><div style="padding-top:<?php echo floor((155-$home_collectionx["thumb_height"])/2) ?>px; margin-top: -24px; margin-bottom: -15px;">
    <a href="<?php echo $baseurl_short?>pages/search.php?search=!collection<?php echo $home_collectionx["ref"] ?>" onClick="return CentralSpaceLoad(this,true);"><img class="ImageBorder" src="<?php echo get_resource_path($home_collectionx["home_page_image"],false,"thm",false) ?>" width="<?php echo $home_collectionx["thumb_width"] ?>" height="<?php echo $home_collectionx["thumb_height"] ?>" /></div>
    </div></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <?php
    }
endif; # end hook homefeaturedcol
?>






function get_home_page_promoted_collectionsx($id=null)
{
    $filterClause = '';
    if(!is_null($id))
    {
        $filterClause = ' AND collection.ref = '.intval($id);
    }
    return sql_query("select collection.ref,collection.home_page_publish,collection.home_page_text,collection.home_page_image,resource.thumb_height,resource.thumb_width from collection left outer join resource on collection.home_page_image=resource.ref where collection.public=1 and collection.home_page_publish=1".$filterClause." order by collection.ref desc");
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: Hi, yes sorry, I need to pull out a larger image to display either using the code I pasted or adjusting the parameters, so the code uploads images in to the filestore and automatically sizes them into various sizes, Instead of having a thumb I want a slightly bigger version, eg preview, etc

Comment: Is the query returning the path to the full size image and then you're specifying the thumbnail size of it? If you remove the width and height from the `img` element does it show as the size you were hoping for?

Comment: The width and height are being called dynamically as far as I can tell, the SQL line thumb is used in the DB all over the place

Comment: @richyp147 How do the images display if you delete the attributes `width="<?php echo $home_collectionx["thumb_width"] ?>" height="<?php echo $home_collectionx["thumb_height"] ?>"` from the `img` tag in the function?

Comment: For instance when an image is uploaded to the system, the system creates different file sizes, eg thumb, preview, large, print etc and then puts them in numbered folders inside a folder called filestore, I have tried changing the syntax to resource.preview_height instead of resource.thumb_height but it says that it doesn't exist

Comment: Hmm interesting taking those lines out makes no difference it still shows it as a thumb

Comment: Im assuming this is because is connection to a SQL string that is calling the thumb? e.g.: return sql_query("select collection.ref,collection.home_page_publish,collection.home_page_text,collection.home_page_image,resource.thumb_height,resource.thumb_width from collection left outer join resource on collection.home_page_image=resource.ref where collection.public=1 and collection.home_page_publish=1".$filterClause." order by collection.ref desc");

Comment: @richyp147 Without seeing an example of the table data it's hard to say

Comment: I can export the file as a sql file for you to look at - will that help, or do you need access to phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Just an idea of the columns available and their contents will suffice - e.g.
`id    name    thumb      preview`
`1     Test    thmb1.jpg  prev1.jpg`
(but better formatted and in your original question rather than cramped into a comment!)

Comment: The database is massive, I can't easily do that, you really need to look in it yourself, I can give you access but you will need to email me for passwords etc

Comment: @richyp147 We just need to see what we're working with, otherwise it's night on impossible to know for sure what needs to change or be added/removed

Comment: Just added a screen (above) does that help you at all?

Comment: in the table resource there are 2 columns for image_height and image_width which correspond to the SQL call, there isn't though any mention of preview_width/height... I suppose I could add one?

Comment: @richyp147 Not really I'm afraid - who wrote this? Where has all this code come from? The issues you're having sound like they would be best answered by the original author of this system

Comment: @richyp147 Yes you could, but that will just stretch the image too large if it's size didn't change when you removed the `width` and `height` attributes (unless CSS acts on it as well)

Comment: It's an open source application that is free to use and amend, but they want thousands for support if you want them to help you

Comment: hmmm there is def not a table that contains preview width & height its all about the thumb, can change the thumbs to a bigger size and re-index the whole DB but that will make a mess of a lot of things...

Comment: @richyp147 I'm not really sure I can help you much further to be honest - are there any forums with other users of this application? This is quite a specialised question and there's a lot of code and database tables to look through in order to try and struggle through to a proper answer. Just an FYI for any future use of this site as well, prepend your comments with @{username} (no braces) like I have in order to make sure they get a notification of your comment

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Brilliant thank you, I will keep playing to see what I can achieve, thanks though you have helped me loads... PS Yes there is a google user forum but there is nothing on this subject within it...

Comment: @SmokeyPHP One more for you if you have time please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886636/adjusting-sql-line-to-include-a-collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <img class="ImageBorder" src="<?php echo get_resource_path($home_collectionx["home_page_image"],false,"thm",false) ?>" width="<?php echo $home_collectionx["thumb_width"] ?>" height="<?php echo $home_collectionx["thumb_height"] ?>" />
```

Why not edit this to set your desired size in pixels, like

```
    <img class="ImageBorder" src="<?php echo get_resource_path($home_collectionx["home_page_image"],false,"thm",false) ?>" width="1000" height="800" />
```

Comment: Hi Arghya, thanks but the problem here is that the function is calling the thumb so if I manually size the thumb it will appear pixelated, the website i am building uploades various sizes in to a filestore, so I suppose I need to find out what comes after thumb really

Comment: If I understood you, you have the src/location of actual full size image. Just use that and don't specify any size in the img tag. To put the maximum size within some limits (so that the whole page doesn't get distorted), you might want to set the max height an width for the outer div.

Comment: Thanks but the image is being re-trieved dynamically based on a SQL call and a function, e.g.:   return sql_query("select collection.ref,collection.home_page_publish,collection.home_page_text,collection.home_page_image,resource.thumb_height,resource.thumb_width from collection left outer join resource on collection.home_page_image=resource.ref where collection.public=1 and collection.home_page_publish=1".$filterClause." order by collection.ref desc");

Comment: In the system we have set sizes for the images, thumb, preview, large etc, the id of the preview image is pre, so is there any way to write into the above function to call the preview images instead of the thumb perhaps?

Comment: I guess you should be having another set of variable with preview size (assuming, you don't want to load the large version of images on page), check the code or documentation if any. Should be something like...

 return sql_query("select collection.ref,collection.home_page_publish,collection.home_page_text,collection‌​.<your_image_id>,resource.<previw_height>,resource.<previw_width> from collection left outer join resource on collection.home_page_image=resource.ref where collection.public=1 and collection.home_page_publish=1".$filterClause." order by collection.ref desc");

Comment: Thanks for this, I had already tried this and it failed, this is because in that table in the DB it doesn't exist, I could add it but not sure how the upload would parse the details to the DB - any other suggestions please?