# Adjusting SQL line to include a collection

Tags: mysql, collections

I have a function call resource of the day which I have duplicated and changed to be called Editors Picks. The function looks in the DB and grabs a ramdom image based on value and  todays date.

Here is the SQL Line:

```
sql_value(
    "select resource value 
     from resource_data 
     where resource > 5 and 
           resource_type_field=$rotd_field and 
           value like '" . date("Y-m-d") . "%' limit 1;"
   ,0);
```

I would like to try and adapt this line to pull in a collection instead, this is the SQL line that pulls in a collection image:

```
sql_query("select collection.ref, 
                  collection.home_page_publish, 
                  collection.home_page_text,
                  collection.home_page_image,
                  resource.thumb_height,
                  resource.thumb_width 
           from collection 
           left outer join resource on collection.home_page_image=resource.ref 
           where collection.public=1 and
                 collection.home_page_publish=1"
                 .$filterClause.
           " order by collection.ref desc");
```

Does anyone know how to adapt the top SQL line to pull in the collection information instead, eg can I change date function to so something else?

This is the 2 pages that power the Code:

home.php

```
<?php

function HookEditorsPickHomeReplaceslideshow ()
    {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__)."/../inc/rotd_functions.php";

    global $baseurl, $view_title_field;

    $rotd=get_editors_pick();
    if ($rotd===false) {return false;} # No ROTD, return false to disable hook and display standard slide show.

    # Get preview width
    $sizes = get_image_sizes($rotd, true);
    foreach ($sizes as $size)
        {
        if ($size["id"]=="pre")
            {
            $width = $size["width"];
            break;
            }
        }


    # Fetch title
    $title = sql_value("select value from resource_data where resource='$rotd' and resource_type_field=$view_title_field","");

    # Fetch caption
    $caption=sql_value("select value from resource_data where resource='$rotd' and resource_type_field=18","");

    # Show resource!
    $pre=get_resource_path($rotd,false,"pre",false,"jpg");
    ?>
    <div class="HomePicturePanel" style="width: <?php echo $width ?>px; background-color:#f1f1f1; height: 409px;">
    <a onClick="return CentralSpaceLoad(this,true);" href="<?php echo $baseurl?>/pages/view.php?ref=<?php echo $rotd ?>"><img class="ImageBorder" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; border:#CCC; solid: 0px;" src="<?php echo $pre ?>" /></a>
    <br />
    <div class="ResourceOfTheDayHead">Our Resource of the day</div>

    <div class="ResourceOfTheDayText"><?php echo i18n_get_translated(htmlspecialchars($title)) ?></div>
    <div class="ResourceOfTheDayCaption"><?php echo $caption ?></div>
</div>
    <?php

    return true;
    }


?>
```

And this is: rotd.functions.php

```
<?php

function get_editors_pick()
    {
    global $rotd_field;


    # Search for today's resource of the day.
    $rotd = sql_value("select resource value from resource_data where resource>5 and resource_type_field=$rotd_field and value like '" . date("Y-m-d") . "%' limit 1;",0);
    if ($rotd!=0) {return $rotd;} # A resource was found?


    # No resource of the day fields are set. Return to default slideshow functionality.
    return false;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Urmm good question, it's MySQL so probably the latest version as it's a new hosting panel install

Comment: Can this part be adapted perhaps? . date("Y-m-d") . "%' limit 1;

Comment: You will have to transform the collection into a sql statement, then append it to the query. I should warn you that this is the kind of SQL that leads to SQL Injection attacks. You should really be using parametrized SQL statements

Comment: @StingyJack Can you help me please? I'm new to all this - so a bit lost with what you said :-(

Comment: So just to say, I need the above 2 pages to pull in a preview image based on the collection statement rather than a random date of the day :-)

Comment: There are many ways to [properly escape your values](http://bobby-tables.com/php) but you **must** use one of them.

Comment: Can anyone help re-writing the SQL lines above pretty please

Comment: So you want the top SQL query to pull in what the second one does?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Sorry only just seen your comment, absolutely that's what I need, can you help me do that please?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP so the pages home.php & rotd.functions.php above are pulling in the resource of the day (preview image size) and its based on a date what I would like is for it to pull in an image from a specific collection say resource.ref and then from collection ref 16 - hope that makes sense

Comment: @richyp147 Just replace the whole of the first query with the whole of the second query (if you want to do what the 2nd query does, use the 2nd query). Then just change the condition variable you wrote in the function earlier from `collection.ref =` to `resource.ref =`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP Tried that thanks and can't get it to work, any chance you could adjust the 2 pages in question for me so I can try that?

Comment: Hi can anyone help me please on this totally stuck now

Answer (score 0):

I am not fluent with php, but this pseudo-code may be useful.

```
string whereClause = "WHERE ";
for each (item in collection)
{
  whereClause = whereClause + " " + item;
}

string sqlQuery = "SELECT stuff, otherStuff FROM myTable " + whereClause + " ORDER BY thing2";
```

The SQL injection can come if the items in the where clause are not sanitized. There are many examples on the web of how to prevent this, but the best way is to use parameters instead of dynamic SQL like I am showing above.